# getting error : HTTPerror: basic auth header is Invalid ,when sending files to ipfs

Tags: reactjs, ipfs, ipfs-http-client

```
const projectId = process.env.PROJECTKEY
const projectSecret =process.env.SECRETKEY
const auth = 'Basic' + Buffer.from(projectId + ":" + projectSecret).toString('base64')


const client = IPFSHTTPClient({
  host:'infura-ipfs.io',
  port:5001,
  protocol:'https',
  headers:{
      authorization: auth
  }
  
  
})
```

i removed headers object and then got error- project id required

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a space to Basic.

Modified code:

```
const auth = 'Basic ' + Buffer.from(projectId + ":" + projectSecret).toString('base64')
```